# Find nontrivial rational solutions to a polynomial system

Tags: number-theory, polynomials

Is it possible to find any rational solutions $(x,y,z)$ to the following polynomial system:

$$\left\{
\begin{array}{c}
 x^4+8 x^3+4 x^2+16 x+36=y^2 \\
 z^2=x^3-12 x^2-32 x+4 \\
\end{array}
\right.$$

except that $(x=0,y=\pm6,z=\pm2)$?

Comment: I wouldn't formulate your question in this way. I would say : does there exist $x \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $p(x)=x^4+\cdots$ is a square $ \in \mathbb{Q}$ and that $q(x)=x^3 - \cdots$  is also a square $ \in \mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Where did this problem arise?

Answer (score 1):

What I write down here is not at all solution, but can constitute a step towards the solution.

It is the fact that, a common factor $(x+2)$ can be placed into evidence in this way;

$$\cases{y^2+28=(2+x)(32-8x+6x^2+x^3)\\z^2-12=(2+x)(-4-14x+x^2)}$$

Answer (score 1):

This is not a solution, but it is progress toward one. I intend to continue this at a later date. The strategy is to eliminate the possibility that $x\neq0$ by deriving a contradiction.

Suppose $x\neq0$. Let $x=u/v$ in lowest terms. Clearing denominators, our equations become
$$u^4+8u^3v+4u^2v^2+16uv^3+36v^4=(v^2y)^2,$$ and $$u^3-12u^2v-32uv^2+4v^3=v^3z^2.$$ Therefore, $v^2y$ and $v^{3/2}z$ are integers, and $v$ is a square integer. Furthermore, we obtain the following congruences: $$y^2\equiv36\mod p|u\text{ and }(v^2y)^2\equiv u^4\mod p|v,$$ $$z^2\equiv 4\mod p|u\text{ and }(v^{3/2}z)^2\equiv u^3\mod p|v.$$

Let $y=a/b$ and $z=c/d$ in lowest terms. Then $p|a^2-(6b)^2$ and $p|c^2-(2d)^2$ for $p|u$. Since $b,d|v^4$, $p$ divides neither $b$ nor $d$. As a consequence, $p$ divides neither $a$ nor $c$.

On the other hand, if $p|v$, then $\left(\frac{v^2}{b}a\right)^2\equiv u^4\mod p$ and $\left(\frac{v^{3/2}}{d}c\right)^2\equiv u^3\mod p$ imply that $b=v^{2}$ and $d=v^{3/2}$, because $u,v$ are coprime. Thus, $p$ divides $a^2-u^4$ and $c^2-u^3$. Again, since $u,v$ are coprime, $p$ divides neither $a$ nor $c$.

We have established that the primes dividing $u$ do not divide $a,b,c$, or $d$, the primes dividing $v$ do not divide $a$ or $c$, and $b=v^2,c=v^{3/2}$, and $v$ is a square. Therefore, our first equation implies that $u$ is a multiple of neither 2 nor 3, and our second equation implies that $u$ is congruent to 1 mod 4.

Rewriting our equations,
$$u^4+8u^3v+4u^2v^2+16uv^3+36v^4=a^2,$$ and $$u^3-12u^2v-32uv^2+4v^3=c^2,$$ we see that $a,c$ are also odd. We reduce mod 3 to get $$1+v^2\equiv 1+2uv+v^2+uv\equiv a^2\mod 3,$$ and $$u+uv^2+v\equiv c^2\mod 3.$$ The first congruence forces $3|v$, and the second forces $u\equiv1\mod 3$ as a consequence. Let $v=3^nw$ where $w$ is coprime to 3. Now we have
$$u^4+8\cdot3^n u^3 w+4\cdot 3^{2 n} u^2 w^2+16\cdot 3^{3 n} u w^3+4\cdot 3^{4 n+2} w^4=a^2,$$ and $$u^3-4\cdot 3^{n+1} u^2 w-32\cdot 3^{2 n} u w^2+4\cdot 3^{3 n} w^3=c^2.$$

Reducing the second equation mod 8 yields $u^3\equiv u^3+4w+4w^3\equiv c^2.$ So $u$ is congruent to 1 mod 8.

At this point I am hoping to either show that $u\equiv1$ modulo arbitrarily high powers of 2, hence $u=1$, or by some inductive procedure show that $w$ must be a multiple of 3, contrary to assumption. The next thing to examine is how the multiplicative orders of $u,a,c$ modulo powers of 3 behave.